# how to horizontally center a table in pdfkmake when it does not occupy the entire width

Tags: angular, pdf, styles, pdfmake

The totals text is centered horizontally, I would like to center the table so that both sides have the same space

[image]

```
generatePdf(template: ElementRef): any {
    const pdfTable = template.nativeElement;

    const html: Array<any> = htmlToPdfmake(pdfTable.innerHTML);
    html.forEach((item) => {
        item.style = ['tableCenter'];
    });
    console.log(html);

    const documentDefinition = {
        content: html,
        pageSize: 'A3',
        pageOrientation: 'landscape',
        styles: {
            tableCenter: {
                alignment: 'center',
                absolutePosition: { x: 10, y: 35 },
            },
        },
    };
    return pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition);
}
```

I am using html as a template for the pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin for it:

```
                       margin: [20, 5, 0, 10],
```